# POST with multiple parameters in AFNetworking V2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am updating some (rather old) ASIHTTPRequest code to AFNetworking V2.0.

Now I am dealing with a POST request that uploads an NSDictionary with extra parameters for the request.

Here is what the ASIHTTPRequest code looks like:

```
NSMutableData* mPostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        [r setPostBody: mPostData];
        [r addRequestHeader: @"Content-Length" value:msgLength];    
    }
```

postData is an NSDictionary that has keys / values - which is based on the action taken. For example - uploading an image will have extra parameters. Completing a user registration will have different parameters - but use the same method this code is found in.

The delegate calls this bit of code:

```
//Request must be ASIFormDataRequest
- (BOOL) addFileWithPath:(NSString*) filePath fileName: (NSString*)fileName ofType: (NSString*) fileType withKey: (NSString*) fileKey uploadProgressDelegate:(id) uploadProgressDelegate
{
    if ([request isKindOfClass:[ASIFormDataRequest class]])
    {
        ASIFormDataRequest *formRequest = (ASIFormDataRequest *) request;
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@",filePath,fileName,fileType,fileKey);
        if (uploadProgressDelegate)
        {
            [formRequest setUploadProgressDelegate:uploadProgressDelegate];
        }

        NSLog(@"filename = %@",fileName);
        [formRequest setFile:filePath withFileName:fileName andContentType:fileType forKey:fileKey];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"WebService must be initialised with PostDataValuesAndKeys so that ASIFormDataRequest is made");
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Now from the amount of digging I have done - I can only see this bit of `AfNwtworking` code - which looks to me like it's from version 1.x

```
NSString *urlString = @"yourUrl";  
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];  
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    NSURL *localVideoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"videoURL"]];  
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localVideoURL];  

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {  
      [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"video_file" fileName:@"testvideo.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];  
      [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[BAUserInfoParser userInfoJson] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"userInfo"];  
      [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[userDefaults objectForKey:@"transactionReceiptData"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"transactionData"];  
    }];  

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];  
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {  
      // NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);  
      float uploadPercentge = (float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;  
      float uploadActualPercentage = uploadPercentge *100;  
      [lblUploadInfoText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",uploadActualPercentage]];  
      if (uploadActualPercentage >= 100) {  
        lblStatus.text = @"Waitting for response ...";  
      }  
      progressBar.progress = uploadPercentge;  
    }];  
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];  

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {  
  lblStatus.text = @"Upload Complete";  
   NSData *JSONData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
      NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];  
      }  
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {  
        NSLog(@"error: %@", operation.responseString);  
        NSLog(@"%@",error);  
    }];  
    [operation start];  
  }
```

In version 2 of `AFNetworking` - there are new convenience methods for this sort of this:

Here is the POST method with extra block..

```
[self.manager POST:url parameters:urlParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {


                // postData

    }

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

            //Success

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

            //Failure
    }];
```

However its the constructingBodyWithBlock I am having an issue with. I'm not sure what I need to do to take a NSDictionary object and upload it in that block.

Comment: What do you require as the Content-Type for the body data of the POST request?  Note: AFN will use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in the convenient POST method. This is not the same as you used in ASIFormDataRequest.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper the content-type needs to be same as I have used in ASIFormDataRequest.

Comment: OK, then try the POST convenient method. Put your parameters as a dictionary in the _parameters_ parameter. This will become the first part of a multipart message, whose content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The second part will become whatever you implement in the block. Something along this `[formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];` will add a file. The part's Content-Type will be determined automatically.

Comment: Appreciate the help @CouchDeveloper- Would I use two dictionaries then? One with parameters for the type of web service (includes authId and things like that) and another that has a list of other parameters - like, username, password, registration details like that? As I won't be using this POST method only for image uploads.

Comment: Okay so it seems like I have this a little wrong. I should be using this type of POST request mainly for media uploads (images and videos) and not only for user registration. I can use a normal POST request for that - with parameters only - would this be better?

Comment: Well, I though you have a set of parameters AND a file, as you have shown in your old code. That is TWO parts which need to be put in a HTTP message body. Thus, you need a "multi part message". If you have just a set of parameters, you don't (strictly) need a multi part message. A HTTP message whose content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" would be sufficient. In this case, your parameters will be encoded and comprise the body. MUCH Better though, you pass a set of parameters as JSON, using content type "application/json". Check the web service what it can accept. :)

Comment: > "Okay so it seems like I have this a little wrong ... I can use a normal POST request." Yes, this is what you need ;)

Comment: Thanks @CouchDeveloper - I've just realised that the multi-part message is mostly for parameters + a file upload and a normal post request is just parameters. So if I need to upload an image or a file - multi-part request. If it is just the parameters that need to go - normal request will do. Is this the correct way to look at it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Uploading a file is usually done using a multipart message. See as a hint and for historical reasons: [RFC 1867](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1867) and RFC 2854, and various resources in the web.

Answer (score 0):

urlParameters should be an NS dictionary. as it is an object that is being uploaded

NSDictionary *urlParameters (make your dictionary)

parameters:urlParameters

this works for me.

Comment: Thanks. I came right with post requests and do use NSDiconary for such requests.